# Simple Product not displaying in frontend

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i written a script in woocmmerce to import 1000 simple product  my script is working fine and it's added all the product at my wordpress site however the products are not showing in front end store. when i open the single product it show the product with prices but when i search the category it's not showing

when i edit the product and update it from admin panel by clicking update button without changing anything then the product display at my store 
i am not able to figure out the issue 
please help
NOTE 
1. i have already tried deleting Transients and hence it's not working

here is my Code

```
$querystr = "SELECT * FROM `table_name`";$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
foreach($pageposts as $productpost) {
            $post = array(
                     'post_title'   => $productpost->attribute,
                     'post_excerpt' => '<pre> '.$productpost->porduct_name."<br/>".$productpost->description.' <pre>',
                     'post_status'  => "publish",
                     'post_content' => 'test',
                     'post_name'    => $productpost->attribute, //name/slug
                     'post_type'    => "product"
                     );
                    $new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $post);
                    wp_set_object_terms ($new_post_id,'simple','product_type');
                    wp_set_object_terms( $new_post_id, 2321, 'product_cat');
                    update_post_meta( $new_post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
                    update_post_meta( $new_post_id, '_weight', "0.06" );
                    update_post_meta( $new_post_id, '_sku', $productpost->sku);
                    update_post_meta( $new_post_id, '_stock', "100" );
                    update_post_meta($new_post_id, '_regular_price', (float)$productprice);
                    update_post_meta($new_post_id, '_price', (float)$productprice);
                    update_post_meta($new_post_id,'_meta_key','_visiblity');
                    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
                    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
                    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
                    $thumb_url = "image_path.jpg";

                    if (@getimagesize($thumb_url)) {
                    $tmp = download_url( $thumb_url );
                    preg_match('/[^\?]+\.(jpg|JPG|jpe|JPE|jpeg|JPEG|gif|GIF|png|PNG)/', $thumb_url, $matches);
                    $file_array['name'] = basename($matches[0]);
                    $file_array['tmp_name'] = $tmp;
                    if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
                    @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
                    $file_array['tmp_name'] = '';
                    $logtxt .= "Error: download_url error - $tmp\n";
                    }else{
                    $logtxt .= "download_url: $tmp\n";
                    }
                    //use media_handle_sideload to upload img:
                    $thumbid = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $new_post_id, 'gallery desc' );
                    // If error storing permanently, unlink
                    if ( is_wp_error($thumbid) ) {
                    @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
                    //return $thumbid;
                    $logtxt .= "Error: media_handle_sideload error - $thumbid\n";
                    }else{
                    $logtxt .= "ThumbID: $thumbid\n";
                    set_post_thumbnail($new_post_id, $thumbid);
                    }
                    }
                update_post_meta( $new_post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
                update_post_meta($new_post_id, 'post_status', 'publish');
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `product_visibility` to `visible`, `_stock_status` key to `instock`, `_stock` key to some value also `post_date` and `post_date_gmt` set to date lower than today's date.

After placing this in your script your simple product become visible on shop page.